# Multiple criteria unique list

Tags: excel

I have a list named `ChargeType` and a list named `TaskCode`. `ChargeType` contains "Professional Fees", "Disbursements", and "Subcontractors". `TaskCode` contains say 0527014.05.01, 0527014.05.02, 0527014.07.01, 0527014.04.01, 0527014.02.01 etc. I'm trying to create a unique list from another named range (`JobClass`). However, I can't seem to get the wildcard to work for me.

My formula right now is `{=IFERROR(INDEX(JobClass,MATCH(0,IF(ChargeType="Professional Fees",IF(TaskCode="0527014.05"&"*",COUNTIF($D$6:D6,JobClass),""),""),0)),"")}` (dragged down of course). So I want it to pick out the unique items from `JobClass` if the `ChargeType` is "Professional Fees" and the `TaskCode` is any of the 0527014.05 items. However, it is returning blanks.

If I don't use the wildcard and instead put the entire 0527014.05.01 it works, but only gives me **Intermediate I, Principal I, and Intermediate II***. But I need it to work for all of the .05's. What am I doing wrong?

PTH = `TaskCode`, JobClass/Ref = `JobClass`, BudgetType = `ChargeType`

Desired output in this case would be a unique list of **Intermediate I, Principal I, Intermediate II, Senior I**

[image]

Comment: You can use `SEARCH`. Wondering if your entire formula can be simplified but would need to see sample data in table along with your expected output (photo is ideal)

Comment: @urdearboy Picture and desired output added.